# Intuition behind $(X^TX)^{-1}$ in closed form of w in Linear Regression

Tags: regression, least-squares, matrix, intuition, matrix-inverse

The closed form of w in Linear regression can be written as

$\hat{w}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$

How can we intuitively explain the role of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ in this equation?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "intuitively"?  For instance, there is a wonderfully intuitive explanation in terms of inner-product spaces presented in Christensen's *Plane Answers to Complex Questions,* but not everybody will appreciate that approach.  As another example, there's a geometric explanation in my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919, but not everybody views geometrical relations as "intuitive."

Comment: Intuitively is like what does $(X^TX)^{-1} mean? Is it some kind of distance calculation or something, I don't understand it.

Comment: That's fully explained in the answer I linked to.

Comment: This question already exists here although possibly not with a satisfying answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624986/the-meaning-behind-xtx-1

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22501/is-there-an-intuitive-interpretation-of-ata-for-a-data-matrix-a

Comment: The final paragraph of my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/165009/919, which provides a geometric description of $X^\prime X,$ is readily re-interpreted to afford a geometric description of the inverse: just undo each of the component transformations in reverse order.  It shrinks a particular coordinate frame by the singular values of $X.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found these posts particularly helpful:

[How to derive the least square estimator for multiple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46151/how-to-derive-the-least-square-estimator-for-multiple-linear-regression)

[Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca)

http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/210sp13/HW7notes.pdf

If $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix then the matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ defines a *projection* onto the column space of $X$.  Intuitively, you have an overdetermined system of equations, but still want to use it to define a linear map $\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that will map rows $x_i$ of $X$ to something close to values $y_i$, $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.  So we settle for sending $X$ to the closest thing to $y$ that can be expressed as a linear combination of your features (the columns of $X$).

As far as an interpretation of $(X^TX)^{-1}$, I don't have an amazing answer yet.
I know you can think of $(X^TX)$ as basically being the covariance matrix of the dataset.

Comment: $(X^T X)$ is sometimes referred to as a "scatter matrix" and is just a scaled up version of the covariance matrix

Answer (score 10):

### Geometric viewpoint

A geometric viewpoint can be like the n-dimensional vectors $y$ and $X\beta$ being points in n-dimensional-space $V$. Where $X\beta$ is also in the subspace $W$ spanned by the vectors $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m$.

[image: projection]

#### Two types of coordinates

For this subspace $W$ we can imagine [two different types of coordinates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124892/164061):

- **The $\boldsymbol{\beta}$** are like coordinates for a regular coordinate space. The vector $z$ in the space $W$ are the linear combination of the vectors $\mathbf{x_i}$ $$z = \boldsymbol{\beta_1} \mathbf{x_1} + \boldsymbol{\beta_2} \mathbf{x_1} + .... \boldsymbol{\beta_m} \mathbf{x_m} $$
- **The $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$** are not coordinates in the regular sense, but they do define a point in the subspace $W$. Each $\alpha_i$ relates to the *perpendicular* projections onto the vectors $x_i$. If we use unit vectors $x_i$ (for simplicity) then the "coordinates" $\alpha_i$ for a vector $z$ can be expressed as:

$$\alpha_i = \mathbf{x_i^T}  \mathbf{z}$$

and the set of all coordinates as:

$$\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \mathbf{X^T}  \mathbf{z}$$

---

#### Mapping between coordinates $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$

for $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}$ the expression of "coordinates" $\alpha$ becomes a conversion from coordinates $\beta$ to "coordinates" $\alpha$

$$\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}$$

You could see $(\mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X})_{ij}$ as expressing how much each $x_i$ projects onto the other $x_j$

Then the geometric interpretation of $(\mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}$ can be seen as the map from vector projection "coordinates" $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ to linear coordinates $\boldsymbol{\beta}$.

$$\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{\alpha}$$

The expression $\mathbf{X^Ty}$ gives the projection "coordinates" of $\mathbf{y}$ and $(\mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}$ turns them into $\boldsymbol{\beta}$.

---

*Note*: the projection "coordinates" of $\mathbf{y}$ [are the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Projection) as projection "coordinates" of $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ since $(\mathbf{y-\hat{y}}) \perp \mathbf{X}$.

Comment: A very similar account of the topic https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124892/3277.

Comment: Indeed very similar. To me this view is very new and I had to take a night to think about it. I did always view least squares regression in terms of a projection but in this viewpoint I have never tried to realize an intuitive *meaning* to the part $(X^TX)^{-1}$ or I always saw it in the more indirect expression $X^T y = X^TX\beta$.

Comment: How should we understand $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ in this perspective? $X^Ty$ is the "$\alpha$-coordinates" of $y$, and so $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ is the "$\beta$-coordinates" of $y$. But...doesn't left multiplying that $\beta$-coordinate by the coordinate bases $X$ restore $y$?

Comment: @whoknows it restores $\hat{y}$, the projection of $y$ into the column space of $X$.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're familiar with the simple linear regression:
$$y_i=\alpha+\beta x_i+\varepsilon_i$$
and its [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line):
$$\beta=\frac{\mathrm{cov}[x_i,y_i]}{\mathrm{var}[x_i]}$$

It's easy to see how $X'y$ corresponds to numerator above and $X'X$ maps to denominator. Since we're dealing with matrices the order matters. $X'X$ is KxK matrix, and $X'y$ is Kx1 vector. Hence, the order is: $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$

Comment: But that analogy itself doesn't tell you if pre- or postmultiply with the inverse.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I put the order of operations